# My Application.cfc logs me off when I click a link after initial login has any seen this error?

Tags: iis, authentication, coldfusion, application.cfc

My website is using IIS and ColdFusion. For some reason when I successfully log into the site, then click a link or button to another cfm page located in the same secure directory it will send me back to the login. If I login again it will not prompt me again for the session.

I have read on other post that this may have something to do with the fact my default page in IIS is index.cfm and when entering the secure directory without defining a page you are sent to the index. It is strange you would think this would be alright.

My default page when entering the admin directory is index. Included below is my application ColdFusion component.

Has anyone had this problem occur?

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cfset This.name = "Admin">
    <cfset This.Sessionmanagement="True">
    <cfset This.loginstorage="session">

    <cffunction name="OnRequestStart">
        <cfargument name = "request" required="true"/>
        <cfif IsDefined("Form.logout")>
            <cflogout>
        </cfif>
        <cflogin>
            <cfif NOT IsDefined("cflogin")>
                <cfinclude template="loginform.cfm">
                <cfabort>
            <cfelse>
                <cfif cflogin.name IS "" OR cflogin.password IS "">
                    <!---Alert no password was passed--->
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#alert_message").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
                    $(this).remove(); 
                    });
                    }, 2000);
                    </script>
                    <!--- Alert DIV--->
                    <div id="alert_message" class="alert alert-danger fade in" role="alert" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 500px; width:600px">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                        <h4 align="center">You must enter text in both the User Name and Password fields.</h4>
                    </div>
                    </cfoutput>
                    <!---My login page--->
                    <cfinclude template="loginform.cfm">
                    <cfabort>
                <cfelse>
                    <!---Encryption Key--->
                    <cfset PasswordKey ="My Encryption Key">
                    <cfset Encrypted = encrypt(cflogin.password, PasswordKey)>
                    <cfquery name="loginQuery" datasource="database_stuff">
                        SELECT  USER_ID, EMAIL, ROLES
                        FROM    LOGININFO
                        WHERE   EMAIL = '#cflogin.name#' 
                        AND PASSWORD = '#Encrypted#'
                    </cfquery>

                    <cfif loginQuery.Roles NEQ "">
                        <cfloginuser name="#cflogin.name#" Password = "#Encrypted#" roles="#loginQuery.Roles#">
                    <cfelse>
                        <cfoutput>
                        <!---Alert if a bad password was passed--->
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        window.setTimeout(function() {
                        $("##alert_message").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
                        $(this).remove(); 
                        });
                        }, 2000);
                        </script>
                        <!--- Alert DIV--->
                        <div id="alert_message" class="alert alert-danger fade in" role="alert" style="z-index: 100; position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 500px; width:600px">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                            <h4 align="center">I'm sorry that was a bad password. Please try again.</h4>
                        </div>
                        </cfoutput>
                        <cfinclude template="loginform.cfm">
                        <cfabort>
                    </cfif>
                </cfif>
            </cfif>
        </cflogin>
        <!--- If login is good then it adds a logout button to the page--->
        <cfif GetAuthUser() NEQ "">
            <cfoutput>
            <div style="position:fixed;z-index:1031;top:3px;left:55%;">
            <form action="index.cfm" method="Post">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" Name="Logout">Logout</button>
            </form>
            </div>
        </cfif>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: The issue was with my host provider server having an issue with the app pool. The caused the pool to recycle which killed the session and forced you to log back in. Moving to a better host resolved the issue.